# Creating a Vala Sublime Text build system

Tags: compilation, sublimetext, vala

I can't seem to make a Vala build system in Sublime Text 2... Here's what I have so far:

```
{
"cmd": ["valac", "--pkg", "gtk+-3.0", "'$file'"]
}
```

Unfortunately, this only compiles the code with valac, but doesn't run it.

How can I make it run the compiled program straight after?

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use `vala` instead of `valac`.  However, keep in mind that this will not keep the resulting executable.  To do that you would need to chain multiple command together—I don't know how to do that with Sublime Text, but on the command line you could do something like

```
valac -o foo --pkg gtk+-3.0 file.vala && ./foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Sublime Text 3 ( by the introduction of "shell_cmd" ) :

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 $file -o app.vala && ./app.vala"
}
```

*app.vala* will be the filename of the compiled build-file.

Comment: I don't know Sublime, but maybe another possibility would be to write a small shell script and to run that with `"cmd"`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest build system to run Vala code from Sublime Text 2 would be:

```
{ "cmd": ["vala", "--pkg=gtk+-3.0", "$file"] }
```

This was my first attempt to create a build system for Vala on Windows, and I wasn't quite satisfied with the result. Several annoying windows popped up during compilation, and after, host window remained visible. To solve this, I ran *vala* in a minimized window:

```
{ "cmd": ["cmd", "/c start /min vala --pkg=gtk+-3.0 $file"] }
```

It worked, but now, compiler output was not visible to Sublime Text.

Since I'm just playing around with Vala and my programs are of Hello World complexity, I can solve both problems by simply compiling the code twice. First to C code to get build results, and then to run the code from a minimized window.

```
{ "cmd": ["cmd", "/c valac --ccode --pkg=gtk+-3.0 $file && start /min vala --pkg=gtk+-3.0 $file"] }
```

Compiling to C only does have its drawbacks, and C-compiler errors won't be shown in build results, but I can live with that.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
{ 
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/c valac --ccode --pkg=gtk+-3.0 $file && start /min /wait valac -X -mwindows --pkg=gtk+-3.0 $file -o $file_base_name && $file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^(?<filename>(?:[A-Z]:)?[^:]+):(?<line>[0-9]+).(?<column>[0-9]+)[^:]+: (?<message>.+)",
    "selector": "source.vala"
}
```

I used *valac* instead of *vala* here to save the compiled program and run it after compilation (the trick described by Roman Fischer and nemequ, but with `$file_base_name` variable instead of static file name).

Also I added two more fields: `file_regex` for build results navigation and `selector` for build system auto-selection.